# MySql MAX query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, performance, aggregate-functions

Given this situation, I have two tables with the following existing indices:

```
CREATE TABLE tblBusses 
(
    intID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    strBus VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT ""
);
CREATE INDEX indBussesBus ON tblBusses (strBus );
CREATE INDEX indBussesID ON tblBusses (intID);

CREATE TABLE tblPersons
(
    intID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    strPerson VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT "",
    intBusID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    intSexID BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    datCreated TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
CREATE INDEX indPersonsPerson ON tblPersons (strPerson );
CREATE INDEX indPersonsSex ON tblPersons (intBusID);
```

...And tblPersons(intBusID) is a foreign key that refers to tblBusses(intID), and tblPersons(intSexID) is a foreign key to a different, obvious table. In this case, tblPersons contains **50 Million+** records, and tblBusses contains **approx 1 million** records.

The persons table is being populated in steps (with a cronjob), and I need to **get the next 100 busses from the tblBusses that are not yet referred to in the tblPersons with a selected sex**, to perform a number of populating (insert) queries. Considering the numbers, this is a little challenge. The populating queries are fast enough, but the pre- bus selection queries are a challenge and too slow.

Currently, to select the next 100 busses, I maintain an assumption that I populate tblPersons with increasing Bus IDs, so I search for the MAX(tblPersons.intBusID), then I get the next 100 tblBusses records:

```
SELECT max(intBusID) AS intMaxBus 
FROM tblPersons 
WHERE intSexID={$intSexID};

SELECT intID, strBus 
FROM tblBusses 
WHERE intID>{$intMaxBus} 
ORDER BY intID ASC 
LIMIT 100;
```

The second query takes 1900 microseconds (fast enough). The first takes 2.5 seconds, which is too slow. Certainly for the foreseeable future.

How can I make this faster? I don't care if someone comes up with a better way of resolving my entire problem (we're all learners), or an improved solution to the MAX() query, 2.5 seconds is too slow.

One solution that I can imagine, is for mysql to somehow continuously cache the max(intBusID) position. I would have thought this happened anyway with the index, but apparently with 2.5 seconds, that is not working well enough. Any hints?

Comment: Also, on an irrelevant note, creating an index on tblPersons(intSexID) slows the 'first query' down twice, this I tried out (in a belief that the slow speed was also caused by some effect of the WHERE part.

Comment: Can you print the result of running EXPLAIN for both queries?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the `max()` query:

```
SELECT max(intBusID) AS intMaxBus 
FROM tblPersons 
WHERE intSexID={$intSexID}
```

You need an index on `tblPersons(intSexID, intBusID)`;

You can combine the queries as:

```
SELECT intID, strBus 
FROM tblBusses 
WHERE intID > (SELECT coalesce(max(intBusID) , 0) AS intMaxBus 
               FROM tblPersons 
               WHERE intSexID = {$intSexID}
              )
ORDER BY intID ASC 
LIMIT 100;
```

This query will benefit from an index on `tblBusses(intID, strBus)`.

Comment: ..So composite indices is the answer then? I haven't seen this before, I am looking this up, but the combined query, with the suggested composite index on tblPersons, and without the suggested composite index on tblBusses, runs under 0.05 seconds. That is impressive !

Comment: I ended up using this answer. Note that I had to add a IFNULL(... , 0) around your inner SELECT query in case there are no records at start.

Answer (score 4):

Try this:

```
SELECT intBusID AS intMaxBus
FROM tblPersons
WHERE intSexID={$intSexID}
ORDER BY intBusID DESC
LIMIT 1
```

I think this should use the index on `intBusID` to scan the rows until it finds one whose sex matches, and return it immediately. MySQL wasn't able to figure out that your query is equivalent, so it created a temporary table of all the rows whose sex matches and then found its max ID.

Comment: How the proposed query can be better (assuming there are no indexes)?

Comment: When you use `ORDER BY` and `LIMIT` on an indexed column, MySQL uses the index to scan the rows in that order, and stops scanning when it reaches the limit.

Comment: when you use `MAX` + `WHERE` on an indexed columns (`(intSexID, intBusID)` in this case) it would do exactly the same

Comment: @zerkms yes, there is an index on tblPersons.intBusID.
Barmar, You mean ORDER BY intBusID DESC ? IF yes, your query was less than 0.01 seconds !! I mean wow!

Comment: @zerkms But he doesn't have a composite index on both columns.

Comment: @Barmar: if he doesn't - both queries (original and your) would still behave in the same way. To sort the dataset it needs the whole dataset to be retrieved

Comment: Obviously not, he just said that my query is faster. Logically they're equivalent, but obviously mysql doesn't detect this and optimizes them differently.

Comment: @Barmar: "faster" isn't descriptive. There are multiple places where OS and mysql can use caching to improve performance. So without the execution plan I wouldn't accept that fact :-)

Comment: he said the original query takes 2.5 seconds, my query takes 0.01 seconds. That's an enormous difference.

Comment: I don't believe it :-)

Comment: @zerkms Me neither. But its on my screen atm lol. Just as yourself, I also think that my screen is lying lolll

Comment: Does `EXPLAIN` show the reason for the improvement?

Comment: I suspect that this query will still be slow if there is no record matching the conditional `intSexID={$intSexID}`, or if the matched record has a low value of `intBusID`

Comment: I suspect you're right. My optimization assumes that the sexes are well distributed through the data, so in practice it won't be a problem.

Comment: I ended up using the other answer partly because there was also the mentioning of composite queries, which I had not yet thought of. I did like the simplicity of this answer, and how I overlooked that. Thank you!

Comment: Did you do performance tests or use `EXPLAIN` to see which one will perform better? My answer can be used as the subquery in your composite query just as well, I thought you were only looking for this part of the answer.